# Maximum weight matching

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ a graph and $w:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} _+$ is a weight function.

The following algorithm returns a posible solution to the Maximum weight matching problem, $k$ is a constant and $\triangle$ is the Symmetric difference

$M \leftarrow \emptyset$
$\textbf{while} \ \exists \ \text{set} \ Q \subset E \ \text{with} \ |Q| \leq k \ \text{such that }  M \triangle Q \ \text{is a matching and} \ w(M \triangle Q)> w(M) \ \textbf{DO}$
     $ M \leftarrow M \triangle Q$

$\textbf{end}$

$\textbf{return} \ M$

Show that the algorithm is a $c(k)$ approximation where $c$ is a number depends on $k$.

The algorithm is very similar to greedy algorithm but I am having really difficult time with this one.  Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Take $k = 2$ and $G = K_4$. After the first loop, $M$ will contain two edges, and since there is no decision criterion to choose $Q$, we may assume they are the smallest weight edges. Now, how can we swap out for a better matching? If the other edges have arbitrarily large weights, this doesn't give a $c(k)$ approximation.

Comment: @MichaelBiro You are right, when $k=2$ or $k=1$, $c= \infty$ but, when $k=3$ or $k=4$ $c$ can be finite i think.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $k > 2$ then we can show it is a $2$-approximation. Without loss of generality, I'll assume $G = K_n$, where the weights on edges not in $E$ are $0$.

Suppose edge $ab$ is in the optimum solution, and say edges $ac$ and $bd$ are the final matching edges for $a$ and $b$ given by the approximation algorithm. Then, we could take $Q = \{ab, ac, bd\}$ to see that since the approximation did not exchange these edges, $w(ab) \leq w(ac) + w(bd)$. Sum over all edges in the optimum matching to see that $OPT \leq 2APX$.